# Why are those kind of posts deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

While looking at my list of 'recently deleted answers' I found two deleted questions, and I strongly disagree. Both are non-trivial (interesting) problems with interesting answers.

My opinion: MSE is about questions **and** answers, sometimes an user doesn't show much efforts in his question but receives good quality answers. In fact this is very common for non-trivial topics, for a simple reason: the less trivial a topic is, the less we understand it, higher the chances are that our efforts are nonsense.

[Is an ideal finitely generated if its radical is finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043247/is-an-ideal-finitely-generated-if-its-radical-is-finitely-generated)

[if $x+y+z=0$ then $(\zeta(x) +\zeta(y) + \zeta(z))^2= \wp(x) + \wp(y) +\wp(z)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944941/if-xyz-0-then-zetax-zetay-zetaz2-wpx-wpy-wpz)

Comment: MSE is about *Good questions with good answers*.

Comment: I have no doubt that those are interesting posts, but there's a guidelines on math.SE which makes lot of sense to be there, and that is that a question needs to have context, attempts, etc. If it's too little or isn't there, then they're  likely to be closed, and then perhaps deleted, as was here the case.

Comment: I agree that for difficult questions one may not get any significant attempts from most askers, but perhaps they may say a thing or two about $\zeta(x) $ like they said about $\wp$ being Weierstrass elliptic function. Context is not just about attempt, but giving some reasonable  amount of information which makes the question interesting to people (including but not limited to asker/answerers).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Nothing prevents from editing the question instead of voting to delete, when there are some good quality answers. Doesn't that make much more sense? "the guidelines" don't say that we should delete good quality answers, which is the effect of the delete votes. Again this is not about deleting the question, but deleting both the question and the answers.

Comment: @amWhy same comment

Comment: Glad you agree with me.  Folks won't bother to edit a question they've already gotten an answer to.  If you held off trying to answer so quickly, they likely would be motivated to edit the question.  So it is the "FGITW" in answering, who guarantee quicker action to delete such questions.  The asker of a PSQ faces consequences, and if you bulldoze ahead to answer a PSQ, you'll face consequences as well.  Nothing you don't already know.  Please help us to improve the quality of this site, by not racing to answer before asking the OP to clarify.  But I'm glad your agree with my comments.

Comment: With respect to your comment to Paramanand: where is your answer to "why wouldn't it have more sense, instead of answering immediately, for you to first have encouraged the OP to improve their question.  Sorry for your loss of rep; but you know the consequences when you behave as you did there.

Comment: @reuns: two reasons: 1) reviewers may not be expert in that topic and hence may not feel really confident in editing and 2) it is not advisable to change the intent of a poster by editing their post otherwise poster may feel bad. I admit that I don't like good answers (including yours about $\wp$ here) being deleted, but a combination of good answer + bad question gives little learning opportunity to people who are new to the topic (they may be just put off by reading the question itself) .

Comment: @amWhy How can I guess what needs to be improved in the question? In the context of the tag elliptic functions we usually don't define $\wp(z)$, for $\zeta(z)$ (Weierstrass zeta) it may be different but it is hard to guess what people with different knowledge want to see written in the question. Once you know what the question means it is obvious why the OP didn't show any attempt: because it was too hard for him at this time.

Comment: In contrary, the people voting to delete know why they do so and they know what they want to see in the question, they can either edit the question or request in comments.

Comment: @reuns You can guess better than us, because you are more knowledgeable in the subject than most of us. You would know what background the OP needs to put in the question so that somebody coming in will be able to help the OP. Furthermore, it is you who are planning to answer the question, so your contribution on the question will be felt. That's why you should be more motivated to improve it and treat it neatly like you treat a possession of yours. We can only do so much and reach only so many posts on the site : if everybody played an active role, we'd flourish.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon That's what I always do, but in the answer. When there is an obvious problem in the question I also clarify in a comment, this is mainly because I assume the OP is there, and one of my goals is to make the OP active, learning new stuffs, improving his question..

Comment: @reuns You have an opportunity to rejig things with the OP of your first question : the post has been reopened. I plan to leave a comment there, I request you to do so as well. But if the post doesn't change in some time, then I'm afraid we will revert to type and delete it. If it does change, then all for the better!

Comment: reuns: No one deleted your post or any answers.  They voted to delete the questions.  I see no votes to delete your posts.  The questions were deleted because they were very poor questions.  That you decided to answer them anyway, is on you. Very poor questions are apt to be closed, and at risk for deletion.  And where the question goes, so goes the answer. Remember that before you rush into answering just any ole question.

Comment: @reuns Regarding your claim "that's what I always do in the question" (motivate the op to explain more), yet you didn't on the first post, where your answer, at the time of this posting, was a "one-liner":  "The ideal (x2,xy1,xy2,xy3,…) of Q[x,y1,y2,y3,…] is not finitely generated, its radical is (x)."  I don't see any discussion with the OP that you engaged with, in comments, nor in your answer.

Comment: Please see the FAQ linked in the questions you answered, upon their deletion: [Why are some questions deleted? Looks like the FAQ was made to address your question, but it's been here all this time, available for your perusal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: @amWhy I am not confortable with your tone. You voted to delete the answers, that's what happens when a question is deleted, the answers (two, each with 5 upvotes) are deleted. It is really far from "a very low quality post". And I also got an answer deleted [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4035391/276986). I am not complaining for nothing (this is not about me, I am taking my answers as an example, for obvious reasons), I am just in disagreement with the people doing a lot of delete votes.

Comment: reuns: I am not comfortable with your tone.  The questions were deleted.  I never voted to delete any of your answers, nor the other answers on the two questions I voted to close and delete..  You answered two very low quality questions, and each question was deleted, not just by me.  I'm just in disagreement with the way you are framing this to make yourself look like the victim, when in fact you willingly decided to answer to very low quality questions. Take accountability for your actions.

Comment: *takes out popcorn*

Comment: The question about the radical as written at the time of deletion was lacking in context.